# remove top divider in android listview

Tags: android, android-listview

In short, I have a ListView, and set divider between items. I want to hide top and bottom dividers.

I have set

android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
android:headerDividersEnabled="false"

Bottom divider is Ok, but the top still keeps the space.

Comment: try changing the height of the ListView from MatchParent to WrapContent

Answer (score -1):

try this:

`android:dividerHeight="0dp"

android:divider="@null"`

Comment: i need divider between items except top and bottom

Comment: then use padding on items